# AWS Quicksight Chart Custom Data Labels

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is there a way I can have a line chart show the data labels from a different field other than the field I have selected in the Value field well?

I have tried numerous Google searches, but can't find a specific answer.